# Cual es la expresión regular que debo usar para aceptar caracteres especiales

Tags: php

Cual expresión regular debería usar para que acepte caracteres especiales del tipo:

& % ' #

Comment: Simplemente agrega esos caracteres dentro de [] y ya

Answer (score 1):

Una posible solución es agregarlos como `Set de carácteres`, cuando usas `[]` en regex indicas que debe coincidir con al menos un elemento.

En este caso deberás añadir en tu patrón:

```regex
[&%'#]
```

Si quieres es que acepte cualquier carácter especial, como por ejemplo `/ | \ {}` etc, deberás usar:

```regex
\W
```

Indica que es cualquier cosa que no sea un carácter alfanumérico.